# Table with Checkboxes - selected all Checkboxes and pass values to AJAX script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox in the first column - when checked this performs an AJAX script that updates a PHP session variable with the selected values. This is all working well but I now need to extend this to have a check box at the top of the first column to allow the user to select all items in the table and pass the value of the selected items (e.g. comma separated) as a parameter to the AJAX script - assuming I need a new script just for this.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.select-item").click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).val();
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('productSelections.php', {
      type: 'updateSelections',
      productID: productID,
      selectionType: 'single'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("danger");
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
      $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've added a checkbox in the first row that can be used to select all items - essentially the equivalent of clicking each checkbox one by one. Not sure how to either extend or create a new script that when clicked checks each checkbox and passes the ID values to a variable that I can include in my AJAX script?

Comment: You could put the ajax call in a seperate function and, instead of just 1 `productID`, you could make it so it accepts an array of `productID`s. You can then use that same function to update a single `productID` or multiple `productID`s without having multiple ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.select-all').on('click', function(){
    var values = []; // will contain all checkbox values that you can send via ajax
    $('table > tbody input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).prop('checked', true);
        values.push(el.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this below code that did the trick:

```
$("input.select-all").click(function() {
    $("input.select-item").each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input.select-all").click(function() {
    $("input.select-item").each(function() {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    });
  });
  $("input.select-item").click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).val();
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('productSelections.php', {
      type: 'updateSelections',
      productID: productID,
      selectionType: 'single'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("danger");
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
      $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It does the trick, but it also does 4 separate ajax requests, where this could easily be done in one single request. In the example it's just 4 items, but imagine that it's a list of a hundred or more. You really wouldn't want that.

Comment: True. I called an existing function as I thought changing and making it as 1 request would mean making small changes in AJAX request and also `productSelections.php`, which I avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This one works well with multiple `table` with **select all** checkboxes.

Featuers:

- Check/Uncheck on basis of **select all** checkbox
- On individual checkbox click, only its *id* and *check status* is passed

Call your **AJax** from `callUpdate`

```js
// This will work with multiple table items
// on page

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function callUpdate( ids, isChecked ){
    alert( 'Check status is: ' + isChecked + '\nids:\n' + ids.join(', ') ); 
  }
  
  
  var allSelectAllCheckboxes = $('thead th:first .select-all');
  
  // On related checkbox clicked individually
  allSelectAllCheckboxes.closest('table').find('tbody .select-item').click(function(){
    
    var $el = $(this);
    callUpdate( [ $el.val() ], $el.prop('checked') );
  
  });
  
  // Look for master checkbox within table thead
  allSelectAllCheckboxes.click(function(){
    
    // Get clicked checkbox
    var $clickedCheckbox = $(this);
        isSelectAllChecked = $clickedCheckbox.prop('checked'),
        $targetCheckboxes = $clickedCheckbox.closest('table').find('[name=select-item]'),
        ids = [];

    
    // Enumerate through each target checkbx
    $targetCheckboxes.each( function(){

      // Set checkbox check/uncheck 
      // according to 'select all' status
      this.checked = isSelectAllChecked;
      
      // Push product id to collection
      ids.push( this.value );
    });
   
    // Call update using our proxy function
    callUpdate( ids, isSelectAllChecked );
    
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```